# What set is this bag or black and violet pieces from?

Tags: set-identification, piece-information

My son got some LEGO bricks in a bag from eBay, but no instructions were included. The only info I have are numbers on the bag 135149 and 2011. It's a number 3 bag.

Looks like "Friends" set, but not sure.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Based on the following parts

[303526: Plate 4X8](https://brickset.com/parts/303526/plate-4x8) in Black

[4211441: Technic Brick 1X4, Ø4,9](https://brickset.com/parts/4211441/technic-brick-1x4-%C3%B84-9) in Medium Stone Grey

[6109934: Plate 4X4, 1/4 Circle](https://brickset.com/parts/6222803/plate-4x4-1-4-circle) in Bright Reddish Violet

[281721: Technic Doub. Bearing Pl. 2X2](https://brickset.com/parts/281721/technic-doub-bearing-pl-2x2) in Bright Red

This bag is from:

[41105-1: Pop Star Show Stage](https://brickset.com/sets/41105-1/Pop-Star-Show-Stage)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found it. It is https://shop.lego.com/en-US/product/Pop-Star-Show-Stage-41105

Thanks for all for your help.